# Why we use build.xml in android?

Tags: android, ant

I am android developer.I am not aware of ant in android .I have downloaded a code from internet But It has file called `build.xml` but I am not able to find out what it is doing and for what purpose it is used please give some advise or some kind of tutorial.So I can understand its working thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at this link - http://code.google.com/p/autoandroid/wiki/AndroidAnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are developing your application, Eclipse is the most convenient way of building the project.

However Ant is most useful when you come to produce a release version. You can set up your Ant build, such that it takes the same source files as the Eclipse project, yet produces a signed, zip-aligned version of the apk in completely separate output location.

By means of a custom build.properties file you can specify source and output locations, keystore names and locations and passwords. It also takes care of any Proguard obfuscation you may want.You can do all this from the command line with a single statement and know that you are going through a repeatable process, not vulnerable to a mouse click in the wrong place.

Have a look at [Managing Projects from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) and [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html)

Take the build.xml from the sample project referred to and use it as a basis for your own project. It works pretty much out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This build file is an alternative (and less common) way to build your projects using ant.
Eclipse (and the Android plugins) do a n excellent job of saving you the trouble - just use the plugin to build your projects and export APKs.

Comment: what are the advantages and disadvantages of using build.xml and also when should we make build.xml

Comment: The advantage is freedom.
You can add things to your build process by modifying the build.xml file. The disadvantage is the hassle around building. Instead of clicking a button that does everything for you, you would need to perform a few steps. (Although it is possible to make it work in 1 click - just requires some work before)

Comment: Sir thanks for sharing your Knowledge Does it improve the performance and what things we can add to the process.